# "Dedicated", "intended", or something else in "tomorrow is dedicated for the registration"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

> Tomorrow is [dedicated/intended/?] for the registration.

The context is the first day at a university. Does either sound okay? If they both sound weird, what verb is a better fit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the two sentences you have provided, neither works very well, as they both describe tomorrow in the present tense.

The best would probably be to say :

> "Tomorrow will be dedicated to the registration."

or, equally good:

> "Tomorrow has been reserved for the registration."

Comment: They are describing the present status of tomorrow. Saying "tomorrow will be dedicated" means some future act will dedicate tomorrow when in fact it is already dedicated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Perhaps discussing tomorrow in present tense isn't a universal error, but it sounds sloppy in this case imo.

Comment: I think saying "tomorrow will be dedicated" sounds sloppy when you mean that tomorrow already has been dedicated and are not referring to any future act of dedication.